# Web page download results file for multiple users

Tags: python, cgi, html

I am working on a webtool that takes user input, performs some calculations on them in python, and writes them to a file for the user to download.

So far, I have been writing the results to a file "results.txt", which I allow the user to download with something like the following html snippet:

```
<a href="results.txt" download>download file</a>
```

However, this breaks if more than one user is using the tool at one time. What's the best way to keep different users' data separate?

Currently my cgi file looks something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# some code to get user input
data = getUserInput()

# perform calculations on user input
results = someCalculations(data)

# write results to file 
with open("results.txt","wb") as fout:
    fout.write(results)
```

Comment: how are you tracking the current user? would you like to have any authorization to allow users to download their files? are all users on your program trusted users? Do you need to keep historic results?

Comment: All users of the program are trusted users on a private server so no authorization required. Historic results aren't needed. What do you mean tracking the current user?

Answer (score 0):

Different files for different users must be of different names. We can just attach these files to different user ids.For example, we can store individual id with cookies, and we name these files with id. But you need generate corresponding html with id in cookies. Like this:

```
<a href="xxxx.txt" download>download file</a>
```